# Stub a whole module with sinon JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

here's the situation that i'm dealing with:

in helpers.js

```
import {funcA, funcB, funcC} from './utils';

function foo(){
  ....
}
module.exports = {foo: foo}
```

in barActions.js:

```
import {foo} from '../js/helpers';

function bar() {...}
```

I want to test addActions.js with mocha + sinon. In the test, I want to stub the whole *helpers* module with:

```
sinon.stub(helpers)
```

However, i have to import helpers first before stubbing it and that where the problem comes in, i keep getting import error from because helpers import some functions from utils which are network functions. I wonder if there's an equivalence to **jest.mock('path-to-module', factory)** in *sinon* where factory is your own mock implementation ?